# typo3 t3ddy - default accordeon height

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

is there a way to set the default height-style in t3ddy?

I'm using **t3ddy** version **1.2** in typo3 8.7

The current default setting for accordeons is set to "Auto: All panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel." but we need it to be "Content: Each panel will be only as tall as its content."